# Angular check if form has original value

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to check if a form with some standard values has the original values.

```
const newGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        count: ['0'],
        name: ['selena']});
```

If the user changes the name from selena to mario and after that to selena again, is it possible to check if the value is original without itering thought the properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to listen to your form and check if the value equals the init value.

```
const INIT_VALUE = 'selena';

this.newGroup.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
   if(value === INIT_VALUE){
       // do some stuff 
   }
});
```